# Issue with file path in Java/Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, inputstream, liferay-6, fileinputstream

I have tried in multiple ways to load the property file from the resource folder.

Every time, I'm getting a file not found exception. My code is as follows:

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/resource/excelfilepath.properties");
        prop.load(inputStream);
        String path = prop.getProperty("excelPath");
        System.out.println("Excel File Path "+ path);
```

My project structure looks as follows,

[image]

What is the needed structure of the file path literal?

Comment: This could be totally wrong: have you tried `".//resource//excelfilepath.properties"`? Seeing the exception's description might be helpful, here. Also, is the code you mention in the `createUser.java` class?

Comment: I tried, But getting system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Yes, the code is mentioned in the createUser.java file

Comment: Please use the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html) for posting here - that will make it easier for others to understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you really want to read a `....properties` file from web resources. That way the content is visible to all users that access your server - as long as you don't hide it explicitly in `web.xml`.

It's much more common to put it into the classpath next to your accessing class. That way you can access it with the classloader and it is not visible to the webusers anymore:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(CreateUser.class.getResourceAsStream("excelfilepath.properties"));
```

But as you are using Liferay, you should use its configuration as well. Just add the property `UserCreationPortlet.excelPath` to your portal-ext.properties and use:

```
String path = PrefsPropsUtil.getString("UserCreationPortlet.excelPath", defaultPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell to the server where your root folders are :

With Tomcat : in the catalina.properties
append the properties `shared.loader` with yours.

With Jboss : Edit jboss-service.xml in your conf folder

```
<classpath codebase="${jboss.home.url}/server/default/lib//proprietes/rootFolder" archives="*"/>
```

I would advice to create a classe to load your properties :

Like :

```
public static Properties charger(Class<?> pClass, String pFilename) {
Properties aProperties = null;

try {
    InputStream aIs = null;
    File aFile = new File(pFilename);

    if (!aFile.isAbsolute()) {
        aIs = pClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pFilename);
        if (aIs == null) {
            return null;
        }
    } else if (!aFile.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (aIs == null)
        aIs = new FileInputStream(aFile);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(aIs, "UTF-8");
    aProperties = new Properties();
    aProperties.clear();
    aProperties.load(reader);
    reader.close();
    aIs.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOG.error("Catch FileNotFoundException : ", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Catch IOException : ", e);
}
return aProperties;
}
```

Then call your new class with the property that you wish :

```
protected static final Properties property  = ChargeurProprietes.charger( .class,"PATH");

property.getProperty(NAME OF YOUR PROPERTY);
```